# Komma bei "also warum nicht?"

Tags: punctuation

In this sentence:

> [reason 1 for something], und außerdem haben wir noch genug Zeit - also, warum nicht?

Do I need the comma after also?

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE. Right now, I can only guess the meaning of your “sentence”. Can you please give some context to clarify what you want to say? (Also, strictly speaking, this isn’t a sentence – which does not mean though that it cannot have punctuation.)

Answer (score 4):

According to *Duden – Richtiges und gutes Deutsch*, a reinforcing „also“ that stands out from the rest of the sentence is separated by a comma:

> Also, es bleibt dabei!
>
> Also, bis morgen!