# Ist »,also ,« schechter Schreibstil?

Tags: word-order, style, comma

Ist ein nicht am Anfang und zwischen Kommata geschriebenes *also* schechter Schreibstill? (oder gar falsch?)

> *Zum Beispiel.*
>   - Der neue Film hat dir, also, nicht gefallen?
>   - Der neue Film hat, also, dir nicht gefallen?

Comment: Es ist mit hoher Sicherheit falsch, aber ich weiß die dazugehörige Kommasetzungsregel nicht. Es ist keine Aposition, kein Nebensatz, kein Einschub, der sonstwie abgetrennt werden müsste, sondern ein Bestandteil vom Satz, der seine »Berechtigung« hat.

Comment: War mir klar ;) Legitim ist auch »der neue Film hat dir folglich nicht gefallen?« oder »der neue Film hat dir ergo nicht gefallen?«, wobei ich *ergo* eher vorziehen würde als die anderen beiden.

Comment: Dazu, gibt, es, keine, Kommaregel, weil, mitten, in, den, Satz, einfach, kein, Komma, hingehört.

Comment: Hast du dir das eigentlich aus dem Englsichen abgeguckt, wo das durchaus gängig ist? (Wenn auch an anderer Position im Satz...)

Comment: @Em1 Ne. Eigentlich hat ein Nicht-Mutterprachler, der Deutsch gut kann, so was irgendwann geschrieben. Ich war mir nicht sicher, ob das geläufig ist.

Comment: @c.p.: Wegen mögtlicher, kurzer Sprechpausen um das also? Diese Faustregel ist leider oft falsch, aber immer immer nur, wenn man sie anwendet; ignoriert man sie, wäre sie - also - richtig gewesen.

Comment: Related: [Komma bei “also warum nicht?”](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/18116/9551)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Die Kommas gehören unabhängig von der Wortstellung dort nicht hin.
Folgende Möglichkeiten:

> Dir hat der neue Film also nicht gefallen?
>
> Also hat dir der neue Film nicht gefallen?
>
> Der neue Film hat dir also nicht gefallen?

sind alle drei grammatikalisch richtig und vom Sinn her gleichwertig.
Das Wort „also“ stellt hier einen Bezug auf einen im Dialog
voran gegangenen Satz des befragten Gesprächsteilnehmers her.
Der Fragende hat zum Beispiel gehört:

> Ich wäre vor Langeweile beinahe eingeschlafen.

Durch die Wortstellung kann der Fragesteller seine Betonung entweder
auf das Objekt „der neue Film“, die Person des Gegenübers „dir“ oder seine Schlußfolgerung aus der gehörten Aussage (ausgedrückt durch das Wort „also“) legen.

Answer (score 0):

```
Der neue Film hat dir, also, nicht gefallen?
```

Das ist nicht nur schlechter Schreibstil, sondern ganz einfach falsch. Die deutsche Sprache kennt eine Menge von Regeln für das Setzen von Beistrichen/Kommas/Kommata, und nur in ganz wenigen Fällen ist die Positionierung eines solchen Zeichens der Willkür des Schreibers überlassen. Hier ist der Fall hingegen ziemlich klar: Es gibt keine Regel, die an einer der beiden Stellen einen Beistrich erlaubt oder gar erforderlich macht. Richtig ist daher:

```
Der neue Film hat dir also nicht gefallen?
```

Da die Stellung der Wörter im Satz auf einen einfachen Aussagesatz hinweist, würde ich auch das Fragezeichen durch einen Punkt ersetzen. Eine gewisse Unsicherheit, die der Autor bezüglich des Wahrheitsgehalts seiner eigenen Aussage hegt, ist zwar erkennbar, meiner Meinung nach aber nicht ausreichend, diese Aussage als Frage zu verkleiden. Daher:

> Der neue Film hat dir also nicht gefallen.

---

```
Der neue Film hat, also, dir nicht gefallen?
```

Erstmal müssen die Beistriche weg (selbe Begründung wie oben), und auch das Fragezeichen möchte ich durch einen Punkt ersetzen:

```
Der neue Film hat also dir nicht gefallen.
```

Dann muss man noch über die Wortstellung reden. Im ersten Beispiel steht das Wort »also« hinter »dir«. Damit wird hervorgehoben, dass **dir** der Film nicht gefallen hat. Es ist also weniger wichtig, dass es der Film war, der nicht gefallen war, oder dass die Empfindung, um die es geht, das Nicht-Gefallen ist, sondern das Wort *dir* wird hervorgehoben.

In diesem Beispiel

```
Der neue Film also hat dir nicht gefallen.
```

unterstreicht das Wort »also« die Nominalphrase »der neue Film«. Es wird also betont, dass der neue Film die negative Empfindung hervorgerufen hat. Dass du es warst, der diese Empfindung hatte, steht nicht im Vordergrund.

In

```
Der neue Film hat also dir nicht gefallen.
```

wird das Hilfszeitwort »hat« hervorgehoben. Das macht für mich überhaupt keinen Sinn. Den Satz so zu bauen halte ich zumindest für schlechten Stil (egal ob geschrieben oder gesprochen). Ob er nach den Grammatikregeln der deutschen Sprache auch objektiv als falsch zu bewerten ist, weiß ich leider nicht. Ich würde den Satz jedenfalls nicht so sagen.

Comment: »das Fragezeichen *möchte* ich durch einen Punkt ersetzen« – *möchte* ist hier absolut richtig. Wenn man sich das als Dialog vorstellt, ist es durchaus legitim, den Satz so als Frage (mit steigender Intonation, wie im Deutschen üblich) zu formulieren. Ich kann mir diese Sorte Dialog zum Beispiel wunderbar als Steilvorlage für den Angesprochenen, dass dieser nach Herzenslust losgranteln kann, vorstellen. Außerdem ist ggf davor noch genügend Unsicherheit vorhanden. Du hast allerdings darin Recht, dass man den gleichen Satz (mit fallender Intonation) als Aussage sprechen (/schreiben) kann.